# How can services of multiple projects talk to each other in zookeeper

Tags: spring-cloud, apache-zookeeper, rpc, feign

I am using Zookeeper, and I have configured a Spring cloud and an RPC project.

Let’s say the services of the spring cloud are `S1`, `S2`, and `S3`...and the services of the RPC project are `R1`, `R2`, and `R3`.

I am able to call `S1` and `S2` using Feign client:

`@FeignClient(servername)`

I want `S1` to talk to `R2`... or for `R3` to talk to `S2`, etc, but I am unable to get it to work.

Instead, I get the following error:

> ERROR 13076 --- [nio-8605-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load
>   balancer does not have available server for client: ssdev] with root
>   cause

Comment: Is ssdev registered with zookeeper using spring cloud zookeeper?

Comment: Hi friend , thank you for looking at the Question..  The ssdev service is registered by one project which is using springmvc rpc + netty +zookeeper

Comment: You didn't directly answer the question. Is it registered via spring-cloud-zookeeper or some other mechanism?